# cannot connect to oracle database server in crystal report development

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports, oracleclient

I just tried to connect oracle database server when I tried to add the database connection in crystal report through Visual Studio 2015

So steps I followed as following

1. Create an empty crystal report
2. then right click on that report

   **Database Expert > Create New Connection > OLE DB(ADO) > Provider > Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle**

Then Following window

[image]

once I give above details and hit the finish 
I'm getting following error

[image]

Error

> Logon failed  Details: ADO Error code: 0x80004005 Source: Microsoft
>   OLE DB Provide for Oracle  Description ]: Oracle client and networking
>   components were not found These components are supplied by Oracle
>   Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client
>   software installation.
>
> Provider is unable to funtion until these components are installed.

I'm having 32-bit Visual Studio 2015, in my Local machine I have installed 32-bit Oracle Client and Oracle Database server that is I'm going to connect has 64-bit Oracle 11g database

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: You said that you do have Oracle client software installed; error, on the other hand, states that "Oracle client and network components were not found". So, which one is true? Which client do you (think) you have? If it works and is properly installed, it contains SQL*Plus which you can use to connect to the database. Try it, just to make sure that you can establish connection. Then move on to Crystal Reports.

Comment: @Littlefoot when I execute "TNSPing" command in local machine, I can see following output `TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 30-JUL-2018 10:32:09

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-03502: Insufficient arguments.  Usage:  tnsping <address> [<count>]` . So that means in my local machine it's installed, isn't it?

Comment: I'd say so, yes. So, did you try to connect to that database using SQL*Plus? What happened?

Comment: Anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to install the 32-bit Oracle Client (not the 64-bit!). Once that is installed, you can use the 'Native' Oracle Server connection that appears under the Database Expert or create an ODBC connection using the same driver.
Please check this link -> https://answers.sap.com/questions/12416877/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle-and-crystal-r.html